# Reshaping a numpy array (matrix) where elements appear in order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with the following shape:

```
shape -> data
  5x3 -> [[
           12 10 33
           9  88 41
           13 39 27
           1  4  7
           65 78 13
         ]]
```

I need the numpy array to look like this though:

```
shape -> data
  5x3 -> [[
           12 41 4
           10 13 7
           33 39 65
           9  27 78
           88 1  13
         ]]
```

Essentially, given a numpy array X, I want to create a new array, Y with the same shape as X that takes all the values (left -> right) in each column of X and then puts those values in the same order, but by row.

I have a feeling this might be a simple or easy thing to do with reshape, but I haven't been able to find out if its doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple enough procedure. We just need to perform two phases, a reshape and a transpose:

```
Y = X.reshape(X.shape[::-1]).T
```